# Why "ulimit -s unlimited" can de-ASLR in overflow?

Tags: linux, security, stack-overflow, exploit

I know the ulimit -s unlimited trick (to fix the address of libc) but i dont understand the fact behind,anyone could help me to make a explanation?~
thx

Answer (score 2):

Accoding to the bash manual page

> ulimit provides  control  over the resources available to the shell and to processes started by it, on systems that allow such  control.

The -s flag define the maximum stack size.

So `ulimit -s unlimited` removes the maximum limit of the stack size and this enable the legacy mmap function.

According to [Hexcellent](http://security.cs.pub.ro/hexcellents/wiki/kb/exploiting/home)

> On 32 bit systems “ulimit -s unlimited” disables the randomization of the mmap()-ing because of the following code in the kernel at arch/x86/mm/mmap.c:

```
static int mmap_is_legacy(void)
{
    if (current->personality & ADDR_COMPAT_LAYOUT)
            return 1;

    if (rlimit(RLIMIT_STACK) == RLIM_INFINITY)
            return 1;

    return sysctl_legacy_va_layout;
}
```

Comment: ulimit -s unlimited only disable randomization of mmap() but not stack randomization, right?

Comment: this article also seems to minimize data limit (`ulimit -d 1`) - can you explain, what that command was called to achieve? https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2014/08/the-poisoned-nul-byte-2014-edition.html